# Dialog won't show. UI Threading issue

Tags: android

I have an inner class that is instantiated inside of a async callback. I would like a display a dialog when the callback completes, so I pass a handler to the inner class when the async operation is called, however, I'm getting:

```
 02-19 15:33:49.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(635): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    02-19 15:33:49.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(635): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@4322fef0 is not valid; is your activity running?
    02-19 15:33:49.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(635):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:456)
    02-19 15:33:49.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(635):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
    02-19 15:33:49.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(635):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
    02-19 15:33:49.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(635):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:409)
    02-19 15:33:49.272: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(635):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:238)
```

Comment: Are you using the dialog in `tab`

Comment: Where are you creating the `Handler` that you pass in?  Can you also post your `Handler` implementation and the code that sends the message to create the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be relevant to your case: http://dimitar.me/android-displaying-dialogs-from-background-threads/